# How to use plain javaScript to traverse dom, swap image, replace jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, ecmascript-5

So I'm converting this function from jQuery to plain javascript and taking advantage of querySelectorAll

Here is my HTML *note there will be several of these carBox's, its a repeating html template

```
<div class="carBox">
<p class="carHead">Porsche 997 GT3</p>
<div>
    <p><img alt="Porsche 997 GT3" height="600" src="img/a.jpg" width="800" /></p>
</div>
<div>
    <p><img alt="Porsche 997 GT3" height="600" src="img/a.jpg" width="800" /></p>
    <p><img alt="Porsche 997 GT3" height="600" src="img/b.jpg" width="800" /></p>
    <p><img alt="Porsche 997 GT3" height="600" src="img/c.jpg" width="800" /></p>
    <p><img alt="Porsche 987 GT3" height="450" src="img/d.jpg" width="800" /></p>
</div>
<p class="carInfo">The Porsche 911 GT3 is a high performance version of the Porsche 911 sports car primarily intended for racing. It is a line of high-performance models, which began with the 1973 911 Carrera RS.</p>
```

And my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carBox div:nth-of-type(2) p img').hover(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).parent().parent().prev().children().children().attr('src',src);
    })
});
```

plain javascript version, is this the correct way?

```
var subImg = document.querySelectorAll('.carBox div:nth-of-type(2) p img');
function swap(){
    this.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling.children[0].children[0].src = this.src;
}
for(var i = 0; i < subImg.length; i++){
    subImg[i].addEventListener('mouseover',swap,false);
};
```

Here is an example of how this looks in production

[image]

Comment: How come you have each `<img>` in a `<p>` tag? Also, did you mean to miss out the `$(document).ready(function(){});` part in the plain JavaScript? Anyway, your code appears perfectly valid to me.

Comment: I like the image in the p tag as is allows me to expand if needed, dont need the doc ready

Comment: Usually a direct translation from jQuery is not a good idea when implementing the same functionality with vanilla JS. What jQuery does, is mostly DOM traversing, and it can often be replaced with a simple object containing the ready-traversed references to the elements. See an [OOP based implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/huxmzyae/) of your code. As you can see, there's a lot less DOM traversing, and the class can be easily reused to create multiple carboxes. If you need specifically ES5 code, the changes to ES5 are [minimal](https://jsfiddle.net/huxmzyae/1/).

Comment: Hmm, that is taking me a bit to digest, can you explain more how this works? Or is there a link to more info on ready-traversed references?

Comment: I added some explanations to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vf14s0po/1/). You can read more about `class` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class), and also about [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), and specifically about [inheritance and prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: thank you for that, random Q but is there a way to personal message users on SO? I looked at your profile and wanted to send an email or message but I don't see that option? Thx

Comment: If any contacting information can't be found from the profile, then no, there's no other way than ping a user in a comment (a user who has commented/edited your post).

Comment: how do you ping a user?

Comment: Just add @ character in front of the user name when you're writing a comment. I suppose you've seen those in the comments of the other posts. Click help link on the right side of an active comment pad for more info.